# Parse ADFS token in Java

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, adfs

I set up login in web application with ADFS.

Authorization request looks like:

> https://sso.company.net/adfs/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=ruleman&resource=urn:ruleman:1&redirect_uri=http://ruleman.net/authorize

ADFS performs authorization and redirects to the app:

> http://ruleman.net/authorize?code=aaaaaaaa.bbbbbbbbb.ccccccccc

One knows that the token from **code** parameter contains claims such as *username* etc. How to decode the token and extract the claims?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flow follows the [OAuth 2.0](https://oauth.net/2/) standard. Please note I am not expert in ADFS, however I know OAuth 2.0 well.

The authorization flow consists of multiple options with different steps. In your case you are using the **code** profile (specifying *response_type=code*). The authorization step you did is only first step, there are a few steps to follow

you can search on "OAuth 2.0 with ADFS" e.g. http://blog.scottlogic.com/2015/03/09/OAUTH2-Authentication-with-ADFS-3.0.html

Authorization request

> ../authorize?response_type=code&client_id=ruleman
>       &resource=urn:ruleman:1&redirect_uri=http://ruleman.net/authorize

you will receive an OAuth code (usually not aving any information value, it is only a code)

> http://ruleman.net/authorize?code=aaaaaaaa.bbbbbbbbb.ccccccccc
>
> code parameter contains claims such as username etc

This is wrong assumption

Using this code you need to call a token service from backend to receive an access token (e.g. using HttpClient).

```
POST /adfs/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1

grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=some-uid-or-
other&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2FgetAToken&code=thecode
```

you will receive an access token. This step ensures you application is really authenticated with the identity provider it knows.

According to the post linked above:

> The interesting bit is the  itself, it is in fact a JSON Web Token (JWT). That’s to say a signed representation of the user’s identity and other grants.

I am unable to confirm that, but you can try. Usually (with other identity providers) the token is only a token and the client neeeds to call a "user information" service to get any user identity claims, however seems the ADFS gives you some shortcut.

Then you can use any JWT library to decode/validate the jwt token (com.auth0/java-jwt/3.0.1)

```
com.auth0.jwt.interfaces.DecodedJWT jwt = com.auth0.jwt.JWT.decode(token);
```

Answer (score 1):

The Postman flow for this - refer [Postman : Authorisation Code Grant on Server 2016 - ADFS 4.0](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2016/11/postman-authorisation-code-grant-on.html).

This code grant is the flow you have described.

As per the other answers:

- Use the authorize endpoint
- Get the code
- Send the code to the token endpoint
- Get the JWT

Use jwt.io to examine the JWT.